# string manipulations in C

Tags: c, string

For example I have a string `<abc="xyz">`

abc can change and so does the value xyz. I need a way to find out value which is between two double quotes. How do I do that in C?
Any standard lib function I can use? without doing explicit pointer dance?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear and that's not C

Comment: Sorry but I guess it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Apparently you're trying to parse xml. I suggest using a library for that instead of doing it yourself. For linux have a look at libxml and libexpat. Under Windows you could use msxml. If C++ is an option then the xerces library is a good choice which is also cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. I guess I will do that only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is *always* going to be `<abc="xyz">` *and* you know that the strings won't exceed a particular length, then the following will work pretty well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getNameAndValue(char *str, 
                    char *name, 
                    size_t nameLen, 
                    char *value, 
                    size_t valueLen)
{
  char *delimiters="<>=\"";
  char *token;
  int result = 0;

  /**
   * Make a local working copy of the input string, since strtok needs to
   * be able to write to it. 
   */
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
  /**
   * If we know we're working in C99, use a variable length array for the 
   * local copy
   */
  char strCopy[strlen(str) + 1]; 
#else
  /**
   * If we *don't* know we're working in C99, use malloc() to create
   * the local copy
   */
  char *strCopy = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
#endif

  strcpy(strCopy, str);
  token = strtok(strCopy, delimiters);
  if (!token)
    result = 0;
  else
  {
    strncpy(name, token, nameLen);
    name[nameLen-1] = 0;              // make sure string is 0-terminated, since
  }                                   // strncpy doesn't guarantee it

  token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
  if (!token)
    result = 0;
  else
  {
    strncpy(value, token, valueLen);
    value[valueLen-1] = 0;
    result = 1;
  }

#if !defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L
  /**
   * Make sure we release the local copy for the C89 version; 
   * the C99 version will destroy the VLA automatically at
   * function exit.
   */
  free(strCopy);
#endif

  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  char *source = "<abc=\"xyz\">";
  char name[5], value[5];

  if (getNameAndValue(source, name, sizeof name, value, sizeof value))
    printf("name = %s, value = %s\n", name, value);

  return 0;
}
```

For anything more sophisticated, go with an xml parsing library like expat.

Answer (score 2):

You have to browse the string.

Everything you need is there : 
http://www.cppreference.com/stdstring/index.html

Comment: To save the OP a bit of reading, the function (s)he's looking for is `strchr()`. But it should be noted that a C programmer should learn most (if not all) of the functions in that list - a quite achievable goal for such a small library.

Comment: sorry, cppreference misguided me

Comment: I only changed a letter to an uppercase otherwise I couldn't undo the downvote

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    char const* s = "<abc=\"xyz\">";
    char a[4], b[4];

    int scanned = sscanf (s, "<%3[^=]%*[^\"]\"%3[^\"]", a, b);
    printf("scanned = %i\n", scanned);

    printf("%s\n", a); // prints abc
    printf("%s\n", b); // prints xyz
}
```

**EDIT** Added check on substrings' length.

Comment: I'm iffy about `sscanf()` because it doesn't allow for length validation (or if it does, you're not using it). I'd rather just use `strchr()` to find the quote marks.

Comment: you have to manage errors with the scanf, otherwise the app will crash for a seg fault while printing a or b.

Comment: Moreover, totally agree with Chris Lutz.

Comment: `sscanf()` can do length validation.

Comment: @Chris strchr() only finds the first occurence of a character. Yes, you can a some extra logic to get passed that. But why reinvent the wheel when you can just use sscanf()?

Comment: @onemasse - Because with `strchr` you don't need to copy the data (you can just use pointers into the original string), and if you do want to copy the array you can get the exact length and `malloc` it. Try writing a version with `sscanf` that properly recovers from insufficient space in the buffer.